# Do I still have to test with older iPhone OS versions when using 3.0?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I wonder if that's needed...who knows?

EDIT: Oh sorry ppl, I made a big mistake here. I want to develop for iPod touch users as well, and they are not likely upgrading so much to 3.0 like the privileged iPhone users do. So for that reason I want to keep developing for 2.2, but Apple is now forcing all developers to test on 3.0. But with only one device, that would mean I have to decide: Do I want to test with it for 3.0, or 2.2?

Now that's clear: If I upgrade my iPod touch to 3.0, I can forget development for 2.2, right? Or is there a way I can still develop for 2.2 while I have 3.0 on my iPod touch?

Answer (score 3):

There is no requirement, unless you want older iPhone's to not be able to run your software.

If you use frameworks that do not exist in older iPhone framework's such as the iPod MediaPlayer access class. When that code is executed on a 2.2 device it will simply crash.

You can test your app in the iPhone simulator, just set it to run on the older iPhone version.

Yes you should be testing on the older iPhone OS unless you want those people to have problems running your software.

I'm sure there are a lot of people out there that have no idea that their software can be upgraded, and i know there are lots of people who hardly ever connect their device to iTunes, so I would be sure to at least still test with version 2.2 and upwards.

You can always revert your iPod touch software to an older version using the **Organiser** in Xcode. Choose (in Xcode): **Window > Organiser**

[image]

You can then select an older version of the iPhone software which you can revert to and do testing from. Likewise in the iPhone simulator you can select: **Hardware > Version** and choose an older version to run the simulator from. Note you will need to have the older SDK installed to do that.

It make be a little annoying juggling back and forth, but it can be done and in 6-12 months time I would estimate that you won't need to worry about 2.2 anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget the iPod crowd who has to pay to get the upgrade. If you aim this market too, it might be worth to keep a version working with 2.x

Comment: Yes, I only have an iPod myself and find it a little bit unhappy that they charge poor iPod users for upgrades, but rich iPhone users don't have to ;) ...well the issue is that I can only have on OS at a time on the device, which means I need multiple ones, right?

Answer (score 1):

If you have customers still using them then, yes, you really should be testing with older versions.

Having said that, it's pretty tricky to know what proportion of users have upgraded. I think we can be pretty sure that most iPhone owners will upgrade soon if they haven't already. It's free, there's no good reason not to. On the other hand, iPod touch users may not be willing to pay to get 3.0. Are you willing to exclude them?

Comment: Thanks... err.. I made a mistake in my question. I develop for iPod touch and 2.2, and I don't want to develop for 3.0 right now because of apple charging for it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have built you app using the 3.0 framework then you cannot test for 2.0, it will not work as the API's have changed for things like the UITableView and would crash on 2.0.

When you deploy to the app store, you will need to specify what version you app is and users who have not upgraded to 3.0 will not be able to install your app. But not to worry, tapbots are reporting that huge number for iPhone users have upgraded to 3.0
http://tapbots.com/blog/news/iphone-os-30-adoption-rate

So keep building on 3.0 and by the time you are finished and approved then nearly everyone will be on 3.0.

Comment: Thanks. That's right... but tapbots only talks about iPhone. I think most of the customers aren't that rich to own an iPhone. Most of them have iPod touch only, and there Apple charges for upgrades. iPhone users don't pay a penny for it. For whatever reason... but that's why all iPhone users upgrade, but iPod touch users don't...

Comment: Even though the 3.0 upgrade for the touch costs $10 I still think we are going to see a lot upgrades due to a lot of the new software coming out, eg games, peer to peer, push notifications that just makes their device a hole lot better. So I still say go for 3.0 (you are welcome) : )